# Start sonarqube on port specified in environment variable instead of 9000

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I am attempting to run sonarqube on CloudRun. But the default image on DockerHub starts on port 9000. How can I modify it to use port specified by environment variable `PORT`?

https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/

Comment: not sure of cloud run...but there would be some port mapping available for that..I would suggest the sonar qube running on `9000` and mapped to the port of your choice

Comment: Hey Jiew Meng, would you please write an article on medium.com or something about the steps to host sonarqube on cloud run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the port within the config file in your SonarQube installation folder.

The file is located in the conf folder.

Path: $SONARQUBE-HOME/conf/sonar.properties.

In the sonar.properties file you are able to change the default web port.

Answer (score 1):

seem like the there is no ENV for PORT in the [image](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/8ae0fadc72fef64334998e811f1b9cf68a458a2c/7/community/Dockerfile) you specified.

so one way to map the desired host port for example `8080`

```
docker run  -d --name sonarqube -p 8080:9000 sonarqube
```

Or if you want to start it on a different port then you need to bind config file.

sonar.properties

```
sonar.web.port=8080
```

then

```
docker run  -d --name sonarqube -v $PWD/conf/:/opt/sonarqube/conf  -p 8080:8080 sonarqube
```

**Use bind-mounted folders**

> The images contain the SonarQube installation at `/opt/sonarqube`. You
>   need to use bind-mounted folders to override selected files or
>   directories :

**/opt/sonarqube/conf:**

> configuration files, such as sonar.properties

[sonar First installation](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/)